# Как реализовать сессию для общения двух людей в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

Не могу никак додуматься как сделать так, что бы два человека общались через бота?
То есть user1 >message> bot>message>user2
Получается бот выступает посредником, передающий сообщения от одного пользователя - другому

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно получить chat_id обоих пользователей. Например, простой текстовый мессенджер в боте:

```
user1_id = "Первый айдишник"
user2_id = "Второй айдишник"
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def send_msgs(msg):
   if str(msg.chat.id) == user1_id:
      bot.send_message(int(user2_id), msg.text)
   elif str(msg.chat.id) == user2_id:
      bot.send_message(int(user1_id), msg.text)
```

Вы можете также дополнить этого бота чтобы он мог отправлять фото, видео и т.д.  проверяв тип содержания сообщений через content_type, но тут как знаете

Comment: Проще через `copy_message` это реализовать, не придется думать насчет типов

Comment: Так а если будет одновременно так общаться 20 пар человек, это будет работать?

Comment: Да и я затестил,такой код вообще не так работает..

Comment: код не работает даже с двумя людьми?

Comment: Вы говорили сделать сессию общения для двух людей, если вас не устраивает ответ тогда ищите выход сами, я предложил вариант сессии двух людей

Comment: у меня есть бот анон чата, все отлично работает с парами через copy_message, в БД записываем пары, и юзер когда пишет сообщение, берем и БД пару, и отправляем через copy_message его партнеру

не сильно сложный код

Answer (score 0):

Так, создание диалога, нам потребуется 3 таблички из бд (например sqlite3) в первой (users) вся информация о пользователе , вторая табличка будет "чатом" в будет всего 3 столбца это id, one_user_id и two_user_id , а 3 табличка будет ожиданием собеседника , там будет user_id ну можно добавить еще gender.
Код будет таков, мы нажимаем кнопочку, и проверяем есть ли кто-то в ожидании, если нету встаем туда, а если кто-то есть, проверим gender, если gender != mygender тогда удаляем человека с очереди, добавляем себя в "чат" и его к нам.
Вот простенькое объяснение )

Comment: Если надо, могу и кодом сделать)

Comment: зачем 3 таблицы? если можно сделать две

просто создается неполная пара, где только один человек. когда второй ищет пару, он проходит по неполным парам, если есть, до дописывается в пару и разговор начат, если нет неполной пары, то создает ее